# How to Install Latest Blender version without snap?

Tags: apt, software-installation, blender

I need to be able to install the latest version of Blender in Docker without using `snap` because it's very complicated to setup in Docker and because I'm interested to know how to do this without snap.

So far the only repository I found is that of savoury1 but it's not the latest stable version. It's only 3.0 but i would like to have 3.2

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/blender
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blender
```

My system:

```
[akiko@akiko-system]:~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

[akiko@akiko-system]:~ $ uname -a
Linux akiko-system 4.15.0-189-generic #200-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 22 19:53:37 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[akiko@akiko-system]:~ $
```

Which repository has always the latest version?

Comment: "Which repository has always the latest version?" usually in Ubuntu Software the version offered is the latest/stable. Currently in 22.04 both the snap (v3.2.1) and deb (v3.0.1) versions are available

Comment: oops sorry. is it `lsb_release -a`? i updated question

Comment: Seems like a possible duplicate of [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software). You can always get the *latest* version from upstream, just like the deb package maintainers do. Since this is for a Docker container, perhaps a deb package isn't important at all. Hard to tell from the way the question is phrased.

Comment: yes actually i want it for the docker container, i thought it would have been the same set of commands if i wanted to install blender 3.2 on my `Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS` and blender 3.2 within the docker image. i guess it's not the same then

Answer (score 1):

You would need to go to Ubuntu Launchpad via: [https://launchpad.net/~savoury1/+archive/ubuntu/blender](https://launchpad.net/%7Esavoury1/+archive/ubuntu/blender)

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/ffmpeg4
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/blender
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  sudo apt-get install blender
```

the above worked on my system; If this is not the case for you, try the following.

in the following link it indicates step by step how to carry out an installation in the main linux distributions, and how not? Ubuntu is present.

ref.: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/about/contribute/install/linux.html